# Convert from string to Icollection Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have Job entity with those properties

```
public class Job: FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{

    public string SpareParts { get; set; }
    public string Tools { get; set; }

}
```

`SpareParts` is convert to string from ICollection via automapper like this

```
 .ForMember(a => a.SpareParts,
                o => o.MapFrom(src => string.Join(";", src.SpareParts)))
```

I need to convert it from string to ICollection

I try to do it like this

```
 configuration.CreateMap<Job, EditJobDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.SpareParts,
                m => m.MapFrom(o => o.SpareParts.Split(';').ToList()));
```

But I get error at bracket after  `';'`

> JobMapper.cs(51, 41): [CS0854] An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Where is my problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this I'm afraid. What version of AutoMapper do you use? What version of C#? Is this definitely .NET Core? However, the error means you need to supply *all* parameters to any methods you use.

Comment: It's .Net Core 2.2. Which parameters? @DavidG

Comment: I guess it's `Split`.

Comment: I guess `Split` have separator parameter and this is all @DavidG

Comment: Try being explicit, like `.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` for example.

Comment: Yeah, seems works @DavidG